# Can time series analysis forecast the past?

Tags: python, r, time-series

I'm trying to guess the past data by using time series analysis.
Usually, time series analysis forecast the future, but in the opposite direction, can time series  forecast(?) the past?

The reason why I do this is, there is missing part in the past data.
I'm trying to write down the code in R or Python.

I tried forecast(arima, h=-92) in R. This didn't work.
This is the code I tried in R.

```
library('ggfortify')
library('data.table')
library('ggplot2')
library('forecast')
library('tseries')
library('urca')
library('dplyr')
library('TSstudio')
library("xts")

df<- read.csv('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dt2ZLOCASYIbvviWQkwwgdo2BdmKfl9H/view?usp=sharing')
colnames(df)<-c("date", "production")
df$date<-as.Date(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

CandyXTS<- xts(df[-1], df[[1]])
CandyTS<- ts(df$production, start=c(1972,1),end=c(2017,8), frequency=12 )


ggAcf(CandyTS)

forecast(CandyTS, h=-92)
```

Comment: Maybe reverse the time series and forecast the future regularly...?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just added the R code.

Comment: Sotos/ Good idea. I'm not sure if that is ok or not though.

Comment: Are you asking for help in writing the code to achieve the goal, or whether it is ok from a conceptual point of view?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. It is called backcasting. You can find some information in [this chapter](https://otexts.com/fpp3/backcasting.html) of Forecasting: Principles and Practice.

Basicly you need to forecast in reverse. I have added an example based on the code in the chapter and your data. Adjust as needed. You create a reverse index and use that to be able to backcast in time. You can use different models than ETS. Same principle

```
# I downloaded data.
df1 <- readr::read_csv("datasets/candy_production.csv")
colnames(df1) <- c("date", "production")

library(fpp3)
back_cast <- df1 %>% 
  as_tsibble() %>% 
  mutate(reverse_time = rev(row_number())) %>%
  update_tsibble(index = reverse_time) %>% 
  model(ets = ETS(production ~ season(period = 12))) %>%
  # backcast
  forecast(h = 12) %>%
  # add dates in reverse order to the forecast with the same name as in original dataset. 
  mutate(date = df1$date[1] %m-% months(1:12)) %>%
  as_fable(index = date, response = "production",
           distribution = "production")

back_cast %>%
  autoplot(df1) +
  labs(title = "Backcast of candy production",
       y = "production")
```

[image]

Comment: You're genius. Thank you so much!